# Can every neighborhood of a vertex in a maximal $K_4$-free regular graph contain a C5?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a maximal $K_4$-free $k$-regular graph on $n$ vertices with $\frac{n}{2} \leq k \leq \frac{6}{11}n$. Is it possible that every vertex $v$ contains a $5$-cycle $C_5$ in their neighborhood $N(v)$? Or can we find a vertex $u$ with $C_5 \not\subseteq N(u)$?

Comment: The only maximal $K_4$-free $k$-regular graph I know is a tripartite graph with parts of size $n/3$. It has $n/2<k=2n/3$ but $k>6n/11$. For any vertex $v$ of this graph the set of its neighbors $N(v)$ has no cycle of length $5$, although this graph has cycles of length $5$.